# How to avoid exponential (scientific) string when try to convert Double to XML conversion using JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, exponential

I am using JAXB for converting object to XML. When I give value more than 9999999 in double or integer properties, JXB convert the number to exponential values like  1.00001997E9. Please provide a suitable solution to avoid conversion to exponential numbers.

I am using following code for conversion.

```
public static  String convertToXML(Object obj) 
     {
     //Create JAXB Context
     JAXBContext jaxbContext;
     String xmlContent="";
        try {
                    
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( obj.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
            
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            CDATAContentHandler cDataContentHandler;
            try {
                cDataContentHandler = new CDATAContentHandler(sw, "UTF-8");
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, cDataContentHandler);
                xmlContent= sw.toString();
                    
            } catch (IOException e) {
            
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          
       
            System.out.println( xmlContent );
           
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return xmlContent;
     }
```

I am getting following out put

```
<bdgAmount><budgetHeadID>25</budgetHeadID><currAmount>1.00001997E9</currAmount><currBudgtBalAmount>0.0</currBudgtBalAmount><currCommitAmount>0.0</currCommitAmount>
```

Comment: How are you calculating value of `currAmount`?